# Problems in Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

if $z$ is an element of $Q(\zeta)$ ,where $\zeta$ is some $k$ th root of unity then $z^{(1/2)}$ is an element of $Q(\zeta^{(1/2)})$ ?

Comment: Surely you need more hypotheses : Take $\zeta = 1$ and $z = 2$.

Comment: Sir.. it means in general for every z in Q(zeta) it is not true ?!

Comment: He has just provided you a rather trivial counterexample. In fact, most $\zeta$ will work for the same counterexample.

Comment: you mean primitive $k$ th root?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: yes.

Answer (score -1):

This is false.  Let $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/p}$ for any prime $p$.  Since the $p$th cyclotomic field is the same as the $2p$th ($\zeta^{1/2} = -\zeta^{(p+1)/2}$), we have $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta^{1/2})$.  Taking any integer $n \not= \pm p$, $\sqrt{n} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ since one of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ is the unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.

Comment: yes i got it. Thanks